# <a href=""> Action to database

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to update a database using 1 click?

i.e

```
echo "<a href='".$wpdb->query(" UPDATE partners SET active='no' WHERE partner_id='$active_partner->partner_id' ")."'>Disable</a>";
```

Comment: Not with that sort of syntax.

Comment: You're mixing your technologies here. You can't make HTML interact with PHP. PHP = Server Side Language, HTML = Client Markup (for presentation)

Comment: you have to learn the basis of client-server communication between html/javascript and php.

Comment: You might want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP and Wordpress development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to react on a click with an ajax function.

i.e.

```
$('#your_button_id').bind('click', function () {
  function_with_ajax();
})

function function_with_ajax() {
  $.ajax({
    here you could call the update.php script and transmit dynamic data
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="btn-save" type="button">
    save
</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document.ready(function ($) {

        $("#btn-save").click(
            function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php",
                    data:{
                        action:"save_data",
                        data:"data-update",
                        condition:"data-condition"
                    },
                    success:function (response) {
                        console.log(response);

                    },
                    error:function (error) {
                        console.log(error);

                    }
                })
            }
        );

    }))

</script>
```

and add to file function:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_save_data",function ()
{
    global  $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update("your-table",
        ["your_field" => $_POST['data']]
        ,["condition-filed"=>$_POST['condition']]);
});
```